# Linux Shell script to copy files from one location to another location and copy files detects same name to second directory then it will auto rename

Tags: linux, shell, centos, scripting

I have a folder on my server which contains some files. Every day i get new files and i have renamed the same file to keep the updated same name file. In the same way, we have to update these same files to another directory in another server.

ex Server 1: i have a folder named folder1 which contains 4 files. path for this folder is home/install/project1/folder1

aaa.dat
bbb.dat
ccc.dat
ddd.dat

**Server 2:**Now the same directory has another server

home/install/project1/folder1

aaa.dat
bbb.dat
ccc.dat
ddd.dat

if Server 1: needs to update a file (aaa.dat) then we're keeping a backup (aaa.dat_date) to deploy the new file (aaa.dat) The same way and same files need to keep on the second server. Thus an application can run.

kindly Please give me some idea or some sample scripts related to this.

Now i'm using
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
srcdir="Documents"
dstdir="Test"
d=$(date +_%d%m%y)

for srcfile in ${srcdir}/*
do
dstfile=$(basename $srcfile)
dstfile=${dstfile/./${d}.}
cp $srcfile $dstdir/$dstfile
done
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I have to go as below example

aaa.dat
bbb.dat
ccc.dat
ddd.dat

**Server 2:**Now the same directory has another server

home/install/project1/folder1

aaa.dat ---> Update file
aaa.dat_20211011 ---> Old File
bbb.dat ---> Update file
bbb.dat_20211011---> Old File
ccc.dat ---> Update file
ccc.dat_20211011 ---> Old File

Kindly help me how I can complete this requirements

Comment: I assume you know how to do all that on command line? A basic script you can create just by putting those commands in a text file and making that file executable. If you don't have any idea on how to write scripts, just googling `shell scripting tutorial` gives you a myriad of resources. If you don't know the basic commands for this, you can also find a myriad of resources teaching those.

Comment: Im using below script to copy and past to another directory
srcdir="Documents"
dstdir="Test"
d=$(date +_%d%m%y)

for srcfile in ${srcdir}/*
do
    dstfile=$(basename $srcfile)
    dstfile=${dstfile/\./${d}\.}
    cp $srcfile $dstdir/$dstfile
done

Comment: But I need to meet with all the requirements that's why give me some idea or some sample scripts related to this.

Comment: Please update your question, don't add answers to comments. Copy-paste the entire script and enclose it with the curly brackets `{}`. That way the relevant details are available for everyone who wants to pitch in. You've stated only one requirement - files that are created today must be copied to a new directory with names that contain the date. If there are more, please clarify those as well.

Comment: ok. i was working with my previous script but recently new files are coming to run an application. That's why i need to keep all the old files as backup and deploy the new source. Now I'm badly seeking for ideas or some sample scripts related to this.

Comment: Again, please update your question, don't add new info in comments. You can update it just by clicking the Edit -link below the question.